# Collaborating on Github software without uploading

Tags: git, project

I'm new to Github and I'm trying to find a way to collaborate on a project on my server without uploading the files to Github. I want that every person will work on a separate branch from his own computer and will commit his changes to the master branch that sits on my server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your question states Github, but there are good alternatives for GitHub available:

- [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) offers similar functionality to Github, with the addition of free private repositories for teams of up to 5 developers.
- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and similar software can be installed to your own servers. This way you can create and manage "your own Github".
- [Git itself is usable on servers](http://git-scm.com/book/ca/v1/Git-on-the-Server). You can create team repositories using bare Git repositories and SSH access. The official Git handbook (behind the link) has some guidelines on setting up a repository that way.

Github is the most popular choice for public Git repositories, and also offers private repositories at a cost.

If you have a small team (2-5 developers) Bitbucket is a great choice. If you don't need anything else than a central repository (no fancy UIs, no pull request managing, etc.), using a bare Git repo on your own server is a fine way too.

I have no experience with Gitlab and similar, but their user base is big so it should be a good alternative too. Gitlab also offers Github-like hosted solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`Github` is a public repository and cannot extend to your server. Although you can use the Github API, it is needed that you upload the files on Github before working on it. You can try installing [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) on your server to get the same features as Github.

Another solution maybe to create a `private repository` on Github and using the API on your server if file privacy is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can stand up a bare repository on any server or remote location that everyone on  your dev team has access to and then have each developer push/pull from that location, without uploading to GitHub.

If you have filesystem access to it, you can just use the `file://` protocol to access the repository. You can look into tools such as [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) if you want GitHub like capability.

If you do have filesystem access, initialize the repository using `git init --bare`
Then you can have each developer add the remote location: `git remote add origin <explicit path to remote repository>`

Have you considered creating a private repository on GitHub and using that? Not free, but it might save you the headache...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to setup a shared repository is to use a machine you have `ssh` access to.

```
$ ssh shareduser@sharedmachine.com 'git init --bare ~/repo.git'
$ git clone shareduser@sharedmachine.com:repo.git
```

You then have an empty repository hooked up and ready to go.

See http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-SSH-Protocol

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, GitHub is not a version control system but a git service with added benefits like issue tracking and a nice web interface for forking etc.

git does the actual version control, and each repository is actually as good as the others, so you can make any repository the "official" one.

Therefore you could also set a common git repository on a Windows file share or NFS share as a remote, e.g. as [shown here](http://elegantcode.com/2011/06/18/git-on-windows-creating-a-network-shared-central-repository/).

Any synchronized file share with proper locking should work, but performance may vary (asynchronous locations like a Dropbox folder will not work and may cause data corruption or inconsistencies).